# Как установить линукс на старый мак?

Tags: linux, macos, mac, kali-linux

вообщем проблема следующая:
Я пытаюсь поставить кали линукс на старенький мак, на маке установлена OS X 10.6.8
Пересмотрел кучу гайдов, но флешку загрузочную не видит. На флешке стоит линукс, но при этом флешка не отображается в списке загрузочных устройств на маке. Мак MacBookPro 2007 17'.
Процессор у него 32 бита, Линукс который я пытаюсь установить тоже 32 бита.

Comment: 32-bit? Вы уверены? У меня на полке такой валяется, там честный Intel Core Duo 2 (64-bit, очевидно).

Answer (score 1):

Записывайте образ на флешку например утилитой с открытым исходным кодом [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/). На флешку Linux я не ставил, но на внутреннем диске у меня установлен Manjaro. Только что скачал KaliLinux, записал образ на флешку, компьютер его видит.

Если вы поставили Linux на флешку используя другой компьютер, то логично ожидать, что мак не будет видеть MBR (GPT или что вы там выбрали при установке?). Тем более, если вы установили Linux с поддержкой UEFI.

Если вам нужен линукс на флешке, устанавливайте его на флешку используя свой макбук.